# MSSQL Triggers for a column value changed in a record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-update

I am a newbie in the T-SQL Triggers domain and would like a hand on this matter.

**Context:**

I have 2 MSSQL tables, **Tickets** (TicketNumber as PrimaryKey,Status int, etc...) and **Actions** (Id as PrimaryKey, IdTicket as ForeignKey, Status int, etc...).

One ticket can have several Actions.

1. When a user updates a solution's status to "close"(New.Status=0 <> Old.Status),
2. The trigger must be fired and check the status of all the solutions with the same IdTicket.
3. If all the Actions are closed,
4. then the triggers closes the Ticket.

Do you have any idea how I should achieve that ?

I already began to write my trigger but am a bit blocked about how and when to say to the trigger to fire the UPDATE Tickets query.

```
USE [DataBaseName] 
GO 
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerClosureAction] 
ON [dbo].[Actions] 
AFTER UPDATE,DELETE 
IF (UPDATE(Status)) 
  BEGIN 
    IF (INSERTED.Status<>DELETED.Status AND INSERTED.Status=0) --Here do the If 
    Exists(SELECT Status FROM [dbo].[Actions] WHERE IdTicket=IdTicket 
  END; 
END;
```

Comment: In TSQL the way to check if you are in update is to use the two virtual tables created (only available in the trigger) 'inserted' and 'deleted.' The way to check if an update caused the trigger to fire is to check if both tables have rows - that indicates that you are in a update. This is a much better and clearer way to check for updates.

Comment: @Gaelle Does `Status` has only `0` or `1`?

Comment: Hi @benjaminmoskovits ! Yes, I saw I could use inserted and deleted, but just to check for updates, I saw I could use Update(column_name) which returns a boolean.
I am more struggling on the form of all of this. Should I use two Select count(*) queries to get the difference between the whole Actions linked to the same Ticket and the Actions which are closed (the idea being if I have 0 between those two Select Count, then I update said Ticket) ? If yes, DO I have to wrap it in a IF EXISTS ?
How will it be, performances wise ?
I am really new to this

Comment: @Sami yes, Status only has 0 or 1. 0 is for "Closed" and 1 is for "Open"

Comment: Did you try with `UPDATE Tickets 
  SET Tickets.Status = (
                        SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(A.Status) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END V
                        FROM Actions A
                        WHERE A.TicketId = Tickets.TicketId
                 );`? [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=83a15b7923f0dee026253a7a52707f44) BTW, I would use `BIT` datatype instead of `INT` for status columns

Comment: @Sami this is clearly a way to do it (I wanted to check by doing
`SELECT Count(Status) FROM Actions WHERE idTicket=NewCM.IdTicket AS WholeActions
SELECT Count(Status) FROM Actions WHERE idTicket=NewCM.IdTicket AND Status=0 AS ClosedActions
If(WholeActions-ClosedActions = 0)
UPDATE Tickets SET Status=0 WHERE Status=1 AND id=IdTicket`)
But my main struggle here is : **Where To**? Where do I write these statements in my Create Trigger declaration ?

Comment: @Gaelle I just give you a fiddle there to illustrate it, click on it and see how the trigger working. I don't know if it's what you need but at least gives you some points.

Comment: @Sami, Ah sorry, yes, Status is a bit, not an int ! I got confused because it returns 0 or 1 !
Thanks a lot for the fiddle, it gives me better tools to understand Triggers. I'll definitely use your fiddle to test it ! thanks again, I'll update with the answer when i'll get what i need :)

Comment: if (select count(*) from inserted) = (select count(*) from deleted) -- if true then assume you are in a update...

Comment: Is the Status column nullable?

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits : with trigger, i already can trigger the updates. This is not quite my need, my need is more How to speak Triggerlanguage enough to make things work ;)

Comment: @ZoharPeled : No, the Status is not nullable. it is either 1(Open) or 0(close).
I am currently searching to do a diff between all actions linked to the same ticket AND all actions linked to the same tickets with a status = 0 (closed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would write this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerClosureAction] 
ON [dbo].[Actions] 
AFTER UPDATE,DELETE 
AS

    UPDATE t
    SET [Status] = 0
    FROM dbo.Tickets As t
    -- update only records effected from the current operation
    INNER JOIN DELETED As d
        ON t.TicketNumber = d.IdTicket 

    -- No records left for that ticket number with status 1 in the actions table
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Actions As A
        WHERE A.IdTicket = t.TicketNumber
        AND A.[Status] <> 0
    )
```

Updating the tickets table using a join to the `deleted` table to make sure only relevant records gets updated - since the `deleted` table contains all the records effected from the `delete` or `update` statement that fired the trigger, where there are no records left if the `actions` table where the `status` is not `0` - since this is an after trigger, the data in the `actions` table will already reflect the results of the statement that fired the trigger.

Comment: Thanks @Zohar Peled, I had found this solution (quite the same as yours) a week ago, but PowerApps API can't update a table where there is a trigger on (Yes, I didn't precise that, but I am working with PowerApps and On premise SQL Server). So i forgot to post here. But thanks, I think your solution could be of great help for anyone with this issue. :)